# Need to use VBA to select an option from a drop down list in Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have successfully got my code to open IE, navigate to the webpage I need, and login. I now need to select an option from a drop down list - please see the following html code:
[html code for the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbRwf.jpg)

How do I select the "TPS Managed Conservative - Dec 11" option from the dropdown.

My code so far:

```
    Sub Strategic_Alpha_Monthly_Pivots_1_MASTER()
' open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    my_url = "http://analytics.financialexpress.net/login.aspx"

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate my_url


    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    End With

' Input the userid and password

    ie.document.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "xxxxx"

' Click the "Search" button
    ie.document.getElementById("btnAction").Click

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop


    ie.document.getElementById("ListPortfolio").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectedIndex` or `Value` could be used. According to the screenshot the value `983678630` can be used. HTH

```
If Not VBA.IsNull(ie.document.getElementById("ListPortfolio")) Then
    Dim htmlSelect
    Set htmlSelect = ie.document.getElementById("ListPortfolio")
    ' htmlSelect.selectedIndex = 6
    htmlSelect.Value = 983678630
Else
    MsgBox "Element 'ListPortfolio' was not found", vbExclamation
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a run-time error 13, type mismatch, at the 'set htmlSelect' stage - is that to do with defining the Dim?

Comment: When variable `htmlSelect` is declared as `Variant` (default) then it should work always.

Comment: Manually i would have to click the box (ListPortfolio) then select from the drop down list.

Comment: See edited answer. The Error 13 could occured e.g. if getElementById returns NULL (the element with this Id is not on the page, not loaded yet etc.). But actually i don't know what is the reason for the error, this is just speculation.

Comment: Interesting - I used your edited code, and now there was no error, but it didn't select anything either from the drop down

Comment: Yes because the `getElementById("ListPortfolio")` returns `NULL`. This element is not on the page (probably).

Comment: Thanks - is there any way around this? as I can see that id in the html code

Comment: Yes that id is there when you check it, but it is obviously not in that ie.document when the VBA code runs. Does the `ie.document` refer to the document which is loaded after the button `btnAction` is clicked? You'll have to change the code prior select i guess...but this is different question. This question was: select option from drop down.

Comment: ah yes, ie.document refers to the document prior to btnAction being clicked. after that button is clicked a new page would be loaded